# angular cli ng generate component is ignoring defaults on angular.json

Tags: angular

Seems an old issue that is open again.
It's sad but on:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.7
  Node: 10.14.1
  OS: win32 x64
  Angular: 7.2.11
  ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
  ... http, language-service, platform-browser
  ... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

  Package                           Version
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  @angular-devkit/architect         0.13.7
  @angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.7
  @angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.7
  @angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.7
  @angular-devkit/core              7.3.7
  @angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.7
  @angular/cdk                      7.3.6
  @angular/cli                      7.3.7
  ...
```

ng generate component is still ignoring default settings on angular.json:

```
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "ids",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "inlineStyle": false,
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "spec": false,
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
```

So I need to set all options on every component generation.
The only clue I have is that it's happening again just after npm install @ngx/schematics.
Just a few days before it was working all OK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have installed *@ngrx/schematics* by this command:

`ng add @ngrx/schematics --defaultCollection`

This command will install *@ngrx/schematics* with your preferred packetmanager, update your *package.json* and update your *angular.json* file by adding the following content:

```
"cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
}
```

This will extend the **standard** schematics of angular and add the functionality to add NgRx specific files by `ng generate` (like actions, effects and so on...). If you have made changes to your angular project configuration before (like using scss) you should update your schematics entries.

You just have to change

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "inlineStyle": false,
        "inlineTemplate": false,
        "spec": false,
        "styleext": "scss"
    }
},
```

to

```
"schematics": {
    "@ngrx/schematics:component": {
        "inlineStyle": false,
        "inlineTemplate": false,
        "spec": false,
        "styleext": "scss"
    }
},
```

You will get additional information at the following GitHub-Issue: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1036

Comment: It was NGXS, not NGRX, but I will try your suggestion anyway.

Comment: I didn't try it yet, but I really trust you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Removing @ngxs/schematics (npm uninstall @ngxs/schematics) and deleting last entry from angular.json referring @ngxs/schematics, just brought ng-cli component defaults back to life.